# Connecting I2C based ADC to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian

I have ADS7828E,MCP3221A5T ADC ICs with me. I am interested to know

1. Is these devices can work with raspberry pi? 
   I want to connect ADC using I2C interface.
2. The steps I should take to run ADC using I2C.

I am adding some of the features of these ADCs.

**MCP3221**:

1. 12-bit resolution
2. ±1 LSB DNL, ±2 LSB INL max.
3. 250 μA max conversion current
4. 5 nA typical standby current, 1 μA max.
5. I2CTM-compatible serial interface

   - 100 kHz I2C Standard Mode
   - 400 kHz I2C Fast Mode
6. Up to 8 devices on a single 2-Wire bus
7. 22.3 ksps in I2C Fast Mode
8. Single-ended analog input channel
9. On-chip sample and hold
10. On-chip conversion clock
11. Single-supply specified operation: 2.7V to 5.5V
12. Temperature range:

    - Industrial: -40°C to +85°C
    - Extended: -40°C to +125°C

**ADS7828**:

1. 8-CHANNEL MULTIPLEXER
2. 50kHz SAMPLING RATE
3. NO MISSING CODES
4. 2.7V TO 5V OPERATION
5. INTERNAL 2.5V REFERENCE
6. I2C INTERFACE SUPPORTS:
   Standard, Fast, and High-Speed Modes

I am using raspberry pi with 18-09-2012 image.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The A/D devices' voltage range is within the Raspberry Pi's operating voltage. You should use this [instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-I2C-Python/) to setup I2C communication on your Raspberry Pi. The AD 7828's datasheet provides information on how to read the data from the A/D converter. You may have to add an external voltage reference if necessary (The datasheet have some information)

You should do it in the following sequence:

1. Set read address on I2C interface
2. Send read command.
3. Read incoming data.

Sometimes, the i2c modules may have to be added manually by:

```
sudo modprobe i2c-bcm2708
```

You can use the [overo-blinkm](https://github.com/scottellis/overo-blinkm) example to tweak and use it to your needs.